# Cannot read property '$router' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, fetch, vue-router

I' having issue with the code given,

```js
submit () {
    fetch(this.url + "/auth/login",{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        mobilenumber: this.form.mobilenumber,
        password: this.form.password})
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log("Response = " + response.status);
      if (response.status == 200) {
          this.$router.push({
             name: "Users",
          })
      } else {
          alert("Not logged in");
      }
      return response.json();
    }).then(function (data) {
      
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("-------- error ------- " + error);  
    });
}
```

When the submit function is called I want to navigate to Users page. I have written `this.$router.push({ name: "Users" })` for that. But I am getting error in the console:

```
Cannot read property '$router' of undefined.
```

I tried `self.$router.push({ name: "Users" })`. Still I am getting the same error in console. Pls help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the reference to the outer scope because in the fetch callback `this` is undefined. To resolve this, you can create a reference of the outer scope by creating a reference as,

```js
submit () {
    let self = this;
    ...
```

Then, You can use the reference as,

```js
self.$router.push({
    name: "Users",
})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked after I did `npm run serve` again.